# How to swap between color palettes in blender?

Tags: color, color-management, palettes

I currently use color palettes by opening a png in the UV editor and clicking on the respective color, but I am open to other options. How can I make it so that the object is not linked to a specific color, but instead to "Color Palette Color 1", such that I can change the color palette and immediately get all colors changed?
I have seen that color box supports this, but I would like to do this without paying for an addon.
Thank you for your help!